# Error - Control may reach end of non-void function

Tags: c++

```
bool isValidDate(int month, int day, int year) {
  if(isLeapYear(year)){
    if(year >= 1752 && month >= 9 && day >= 13){
      if((month == 9 || month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 11) &&     (day <= 30)){
        return true;
      }
      else if((month == 2) && (day <= 29)){
        return true;
      }
      else if(((month >= 1 && month <= 3) || (month >=5 && month <= 8) || month == 10 || month == 12) && (day <= 31)){
        return true;
      }
      else{
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    if(year >= 1752 && month >= 9 && day >= 13){
      if((month == 9 || month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 11) && (day <= 30)){
        return true;
      }
      else if((month == 2) && (day <= 28)){
        return true;
      }
      else if(((month >= 1 && month <= 3) || (month >=5 && month <= 8) || month == 10 || month == 12) && (day <= 31)){
        return true;
      }
      else{
        return false;
      }
    }
   }
}
```

I don't get why I get such error. There can only be two possible routes, so that means there will definitely be a return value. I'm very confused. Please help!

Comment: I smell a formatting issue. Be warned question editors!

Answer (score 1):

There's one possible route where no return is called. It's if `if(year >= 1752 && month >= 9 && day >= 13)` does not evaluate to true.

```
else{
    if(year >= 1752 && month >= 9 && day >= 13){
        if((month == 9 || month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 11) && (day <= 30)){
            return true;
        }
        else if((month == 2) && (day <= 28)){
            return true;
        }
        else if(((month >= 1 && month <= 3) || (month >=5 && month <= 8) || month == 10 || month == 12) && (day <= 31)){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    // return here
}
```

Comment: Two routes: the same problem exists in the first `if` block too.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "else" for this if:

```
if(year >= 1752 && month >= 9 && day >= 13){
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `return` at the end of function that can be reached if `(year >= 1752 && month >= 9 && day >= 13)` is `false`.

Note that the above `if` may work not as you expect. Probably you want to treat as valid only dates after 1752 Sep 13. But it counts any date with month before September as not valid. You may want on the function beginning:

```
if (year < 1752)
    return false;
else if (year == 1752) {
    if (month < 9 || (month == 9 && day < 13))
        return false;
}
```

By the way, you do not have to duplicate all blocks for leap and non leap years. The check `isLeapYear()` may be done only if `month == 2`